# How To Do A Contains Query On A StrField

Tags: solr

I have a Solr 3.5 index, and I need to run a quick **contains query** for debugging purposes.

The column is of type **StrField**, and I need to do something like `q=FieldName:*.MP4`

---

I know a permanent solution would be to re-index the field as an ngram, but this is just a quick one time query and I was wondering if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are using Solr 3.5, queries starting with a wildcard are not supported. However, you can create a reverse index of all your terms. This means that you will index all your terms backwards, and than your query will look something like q==FieldName:4pm.*

Comment: Time for an upgrade I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Solr 4.0+ you can do a regex query:

```
q=FieldName:/.*%5C.MP4/
```

where `%5C` is URL-encoding for `\`.

**Update:** Well, you don't even need that. Your query

```
q=FieldName:*.MP4
```

should work. I tried it in 4.0 and 3.6.1 and it worked fine.

And if you want `*.mp4` as well, then do an OR query like this:

```
q=FieldName:(*.MP4 OR *.mp4)
```

**Update 2:** Since your Solr version is 3.5 which you added to your question later, I guess both the options above aren't going to work for you. I guess you will need to re-index, unless someone knows how to turn leading wild-card ON in solr 3.5.

Comment: I get an error about using "a leading wildcard character" when I try q=FieldName:*.MP4

Comment: Update: all I can find to allow leading wild card queries is QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true ).  This wont work for me because I'm executing the query over rest. Is there a way to do this in the querystring, or in the solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Which Solr version are you using? I tried it in 4.0 and 3.6 and leading wild card worked. See http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/solr-user/12bc10xe6y/is-leading-wildcard-search-turned-on-by-default-in-solr-3-6-1

Comment: It is 3.5 - exact message is Cannot parse 'FieldName:*.mp4 ': '*' or '?' not allowed as first character in WildcardQuery